# partial derivative notation question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, notation

I'm reading a book called *Correlated Data Analysis, Analytics, and Applications* and I simply don't understand some notation.  The author says, in chapter 2, page 26:

> A unit deviance is called regular if function $d(y;u)$ is twice continuously differentiable with respect to $(y, \mu)$ on $\Omega  \times \Omega$ and satisfies
>   $$ \frac{ \partial^2 d}{\partial \mu^2}(y;y) = \frac{ \partial^2 d}{\partial \mu^2}(y;\mu) \Bigg|_{\mu=y} >0,\quad \forall y \in \Omega$$

Um... what does that notation mean?  On the left, I guess I take the second partial derivative then evaluate with y as both variables?  In the right case, I have no idea...

Could someone share an example of a function where this would not be true?

Thank you.

Edit: you can view this in place by [downloading this sample pdf](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387713922-c2.pdf) (logical page 26, pdf page 4)

Comment: It looks like the author should have use "$:=$" instead of just "$=$".

Comment: I think that on the right you take the derivative with respect to u evaluated at y and u.  Then take the limit as u goes to y.  This looks as if the two sides should be exactly identical.  However, I'm wondering about discontinuity in the 2nd partial derivative -- that could make them different.  Then again, if that's the problem it surely could be stated directly.